# How do I resize image but maintain features in the image? Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, encoding

I have an image that looks like this: [image]

```
    array.resize(20,20,3)

    img = Image.fromarray(array, 'RGB')
    img.save('my.png',quality=90)

    img.show()
```

It is currently a 500x500x3 NumPy array. The underlying space is a 20x20 grid of cells and I want to resize the image so that each grid cell has entries in a 20x20x3 NumPy Array corresponding to it's RGB values instead of (500/20)*(500/20)*3 entries per cell.

The code above does not seem to work unfortunately as it seems to be giving more entries per cell than I expected although I am not 100% sure.

Comment: do you mean [Image.resize()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize) on original image ? `img = original_image.resize((20,20))` ?

Comment: Yes , ``` new_image_array=original_image_array.resize(20,20,3)```

Comment: numpy resize function and method are not appropriate for images.  Hopefully the docs make that clear.

Comment: but `Image.resize` may create pixel with half tones - maybe you should create function with get every cell (25x25 pixels) separatelly and get value from cell to create new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resize image with `pillow` you can use [Image.resize()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.2.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize)

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request
import numpy as np

data = urllib.request.urlopen('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bPlZ.png')
old_img = Image.open(data)

new_img = old_img.resize((20, 20))
new_img.save('my.png',quality=90)
new_img.show()

array = np.array(new_img)

print(array)
```

But resizing image you can create pixels with half-tones.

Maybe you should get values directly from `numpy.array`. You have solid colors so you could get single pixel from every cell - because every cell has size `25x25` so it could be:

```
new_array = old_array[::25,::25,:]
```

and then you don't have to convert to image.

And if you convert this array to image then it should be sharper than create with `Image.resize`.

[image]

```
from PIL import Image
import urllib.request
import numpy as np

data = urllib.request.urlopen('https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bPlZ.png')
old_img = Image.open(data)

old_array = np.array(old_img)

new_array = array[::25,::25,:]

print(new_array)

new_img = Image.fromarray(new_array)
new_img.save('my.png',quality=90)
new_img.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
size = 20, 20
img = Image.fromarray(array, 'RGB')
img.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
img.save('my.png',quality=90)

img.show()
```